# when second or any other image radio button is clicked, the first one gets updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where menu has to be uploaded with menu title and type. The type can be food-menu and beverage-menu. Each type will have only 3 images. I have done that part 
but when selecting the radio button for menu type, if i select second or other than first radio button, the first radio button gets selected. How do I solve this issue?

The code can be large so here is the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/zxxrnw2qx4

here is the code in brief

```
const Preview = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.files.map((file, index) => {
        if (['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'].includes(file.type)) {
          return (
            <ClientUploadedImage
              key={index}
              file={file}
              id={index}
              menu_title={props.menu_title}
              type={props.type}
              foodmenuError={props.foodmenuError}
              handleChange={props.handleChange}
              handleTypeChange={props.handleTypeChange}
            />
          );
        }
        return <div>No File to Show Preview</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};


const ClientUploadedImage = props => {
  return (
    <section id="menus-photo">
      <img src={props.file.preview} width={'400px'} height={'auto'} />
      <div className="content">
        <form className="form">
          <Radio
            value="food-menu"
            label={`Food Menu${props.id}`}
            name={props.id}
            handleChangeEvent={props.handleTypeChange}
            isChecked={props.type[props.id] === 'food-menu'}
          />
          <Radio
            value="beverages-menu"
            label={'Beverages Menu'}
            name={props.id}
            handleChangeEvent={props.handleTypeChange}
            isChecked={props.type[props.id] === 'beverages-menu'}
          />
          <InputField
            name={props.id}
            type="text"
            label="Menu Title"
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            value={props.menu_title[props.id]}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your type array is empty in initial state. If you directly select radio button from second image, handleTypeChange is being called with index 1. In the function, `...types.slice(0, index)` becomes `types.slice(0,1)` which eventually performs spread operation on a blank array and your newValue is appended at 0th position which leads to selection of first image radio button. Here you need to handle the blank array condition for first selection inside the function and you will be good to go.

Comment: That is what I could not figured out. Did you find out the issue from the demo?

Comment: The radio buttons are working fine for me. I even checked console. In .type[0] correct value is getting stored depending on the radio button selection.

Comment: Did you first select the second image radio button or first image radio button?

Comment: I first selected Food Menu radio button and then Beverage Menu and the other way round also worked for me.

Comment: I am not saying that. What I am saying is upload two image first, then select the radio button of second image not of first image and you will see the bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154614/discussion-between-pri-and-akash-verma).